# OnePlatformRpcException. Google play console error, under in app products

Tags: google-play-console

When I click on in app products, on the google play console. Either Subcsriptions or managed products, I get this error, in a red bar along the top:

OnePlatformRpcException: status: code: 9 message: Precondition check failed. , request: RpcRequestz_play.console.apps.api.payments.PaymentsService_ListPaymentsAlerts, httpStatus: 400, stackTrace: null

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Did you report this to Google?

Comment: Yes, they said they are looking into it, and never (yet) got back to me,